# Multiple relationships between two models

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using code first and EF 4.1 im my MVC3 App and have two models that have two
 relationships between them. Here is the classes that refers to these models:

```
    public class Cattle
    {
        public int CattleID { get; set; }
        public int FarmID { get; set; }
        public int SituationID { get; set; }
        public int DiscardID { get; set; }
        public int Stamp { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Condition { get; set; }
        public virtual Farm Farm { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Cattles2")]
        public virtual ICollection<Farm> Farms { get; set; }
    }

 public class Farm
 {
    public int FarmID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cattle> Cattles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cattle> Cattles2 { get; set; }
 }
```

One relationship is one to one or many cause a catle can only be in a farm and a farm can contains many catles. Another relationship is many to many that a catle can be transferred between farms and i would generate a third table to store the transfers using Fluent API. I also would like to insert a Date property to the new table and don´t know how to do it.Here is the code in the FarmContext inside the OnModelCreating method:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Catle>()
         .HasMany(c => c.Farms).WithMany(i => i.Catles)
         .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("CatleID")
             .MapRightKey("FarmID")
             .ToTable("CatleTransfer"));
```

When i build the project it seems to work fine and the generated tables Catle and Farm are fed by the FarmInitializer but some information that points to this relationship is missing in the index page of Catle. its appearing in blank to me. Here is the code that gets the information:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Farm.Name)
```

I need Knowing what i am doing wrong or if there is a more appropriate method to resolve that issue.

Comment: Is `Farm` populated or is it null? Is `FarmID` correctly populated? How is the information about new Date property related to the problem?

Comment: yes, the Farm table are correctly populated and the catle table too. The FarmID is populated in both tables. The Date property stores the date of a catle´s transfer from its actual farm to the new farm. Hope i have helped.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking about .NET code not about database.

Comment: The navigation property Farm is null and the Navigation Property Farms is making count=0.FarmID is populated and if i remove the many to many relationship, i get the information i need "Farm.Name". But i need knowing how i work with multiple relationships between two models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to be specific about the relationship when dealing with multiple joins.

Try adding a Foreign Key attribute to your Farm navigation property.

```
[ForeignKey("FarmID")]
public virtual Farm Farm { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry,but it didn´t work. Shows me the following error: "The referential relationship will result in a cyclic reference that is not allowed"

Comment: You should be able to stop cycles or multiple cascade paths by allowing nulls for FarmId  (public int? FarmID { get; set; }) or disabling cascade for the relationship with the modelBuilder.

Comment: Ok, I set the FarmID property as nullable and it worked fine, THX a lot. And what about generate the Date property to the new table "CatleTransfer" shown in the code...Could you help me?

Comment: If you want to have additional fields in your joining table.  You'll need to add that to your model as its own class.  Then change both of your navigation properties to use that class.  (e.g. ICollection<CattleTransfer> CattleTransfers)

Comment: Thx ckal. Now the system is working fine and that´s ending my question. Bye!!